# delete button not deleting from view right away in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a calendar where I also let users delete events. However, when delete button is pressed it prompts user to delete event - they said yes. But the event stays on calendar (not deleting) but when I refresh the page the event is gone. Can anyone see my javascript of what I have done wrong. thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
      var PUBLIC_KEY = "PUBLIC_KEY",
        CALENDAR_ID = "CALENDAR_ID";

    var events = []
    events = parselocalstorage('events')
    var renderPopup = function (jsEvent, start, end, calEvent) {
        var $popup = $('#calendar-popup');
        var $eventForm = $('#event-form');
        $event = $('#event');
        var $selectedElmt = $(jsEvent.target);
        var relativeStartDay = start.calendar(null, { lastDay: '[yesterday]', sameDay: '[today]' });
        var endNextDay = '';
        if (relativeStartDay === 'yesterday') {
            endNextDay = '[Today at] ';
        }
        else if (relativeStartDay === 'today') {
            endNextDay = '[Tomorrow at] ';
        }
        else {
            endNextDay = 'dddd ';
        }





        $('.start-time').html(

             '<time datetime="' + start.format() + '">'
            + start.calendar(null, {
                lastWeek: 'L LT',
                nextWeek: 'dddd LT',
                sameElse: 'L LT'
            })
            + '</time>'
        );




        if (calEvent) {
            $eventForm.hide();

            $event.children('header').html(`<i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>`);
            $event.find('.location').text(calEvent.location ? calEvent.location : '(No location information.)');
            $event.find('.details').text(calEvent.details ? calEvent.details : '');
            $event.show();
        }

        else {
            $event.hide();
            $('#event-start').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm'));
            $eventForm.show();
        }
        var leftPosition = 0;
        var $prong = $('.prong');
        var prongPos = 0;
        if ($selectedElmt.hasClass('fc-highlight')) {
            leftPosition = $selectedElmt.offset().left - $popup.width() + ($selectedElmt.width() / 2);
            if (leftPosition <= 0) {
                leftPosition = 5;
                prongPos = $popup.width() - $selectedElmt.offset().left - 30
            }
            else {
                prongPos = 15;
            }
            $popup.css('left', leftPosition);
            $prong.css({
                'left': '',
                'right': prongPos,
                'float': 'right'
            });
        }
        else {
            leftPosition = jsEvent.originalEvent.pageX - $popup.width() / 2;
            if (leftPosition <= 0) {
                leftPosition = 5;
            }
            prongPos = jsEvent.originalEvent.pageX - leftPosition - ($prong.width() * 1.7);
            $popup.css('left', leftPosition);
            $prong.css({
                'left': prongPos,
                'float': 'none',
                'right': ''
            });
        }
        var topPosition = (calEvent ? jsEvent.originalEvent.pageY : $selectedElmt.offset().top) - $popup.height() - 15;
        if ((topPosition <= window.pageYOffset)
            && !((topPosition + $popup.height()) > window.innerHeight)) {
            $popup.css('top', jsEvent.originalEvent.pageY + 15);
            $prong.css('top', -($popup.height() + 12))
                .children('div:first-child').removeClass('bottom-prong-dk').addClass('top-prong-dk')
                .next().removeClass('bottom-prong-lt').addClass('top-prong-lt');
        }
        else {
            $popup.css('top', topPosition);
            $prong.css({ 'top': 0, 'bottom': 0 })
                .children('div:first-child').removeClass('top-prong-dk').addClass('bottom-prong-dk')
                .next().removeClass('top-prong-lt').addClass('bottom-prong-lt');
        }
        $popup.show();
        $popup.find('input[type="text"]:first').focus();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           header: {
                left: 'title',
                right: 'prev,next today'
            },
            timezone: 'local',
            defaultView: 'month',
            allDayDefault: false,
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotEventOverlap: true,
            slotDuration: "01:00:00",
           slotLabelInterval: "01:00:00",
            snapDuration: "00:15:00",
            contentHeight: 700,
            scrollTime: "8:00:00",
            axisFormat: 'h:mm a',
            timeFormat: 'h:mm A()',
            selectable: true,
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                let arr = parselocalstorage('events')
                callback(arr);
            },
            eventColor: '#1a73e8',
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent) {
                renderPopup(jsEvent, calEvent.start, calEvent.end, calEvent);
             },
             eventRender: function (event, element) {
                 element.append(`<span class='I_delete'><i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x"></i></span>`);

                 element.find(".I_delete").click(function () {
                     $('#calendar-popup').hide();
                     if (confirm('are you sure want to delete event?')) {
                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                         var index = events.map(function (x) { return x.id; }).indexOf(event.id);
                         events.splice(index, 1);
                         localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events));

                         events = parselocalstorage('events')

                     }
                 });








              $('#close-btnid').click(function () {
                    $('#simplemodal').hide();
                })
                var modal = document.getElementById('simplemodal')
                window.addEventListener('click', clickOutside)
                function clickOutside(e) {
                    if (e.target == modal) {
                        modal.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            },
            select: function (start, end, jsEvent) {
                $('.btn-primary').css('opacity', 1)
                $('.btn-primary').click(function () {
                    renderPopup(jsEvent, start.local(), end.local());
                })
                renderPopup(jsEvent, start.local(), end.local());
            },
            load: function (options) {
                var result = $.Deferred();
                $.ajax({
                    data: { showDeleted: true },
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: [
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/",
                        CALENDAR_ID,
                        "/events?key=",
                        PUBLIC_KEY
                    ].join("")
                }).done(function (response) {
                    result.resolve(response.items);
                });
                return result.promise();
            },
        });
        //event-form
        $('#event-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $form = $(e.currentTarget);
            $title = $form.find('input#event-title');
           // $location = $form.find('input#eventname');
            $details = $form.find('textarea#event-details');
            $ID = '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)
            events.push({
                id: $ID,
                title: $title.val(),
                 start: $form.find('input#event-start').val(),
             //  location: $location.val(),
                details: $details.val()
            });
            $title.val('');


            $details.val('');
            $form.parent().blur().hide();
            localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events));
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        });
        //Set hide action for ESC key event


       $('#calendar-popup').on('keydown', function (e) {
            $this = $(this);
            console.log($this);
            if ($this.is(':visible') && e.which === 27) {
                $this.blur();
            }
        })
            //Set hide action for lost focus event
            .on('focusout', function (e) {
                $this = $(this);
                if ($this.is(':visible') && !$(e.relatedTarget).is('#calendar-popup, #calendar-popup *')) {
                    $this.hide();
                }
            });
    });


    function clearDialog() {
        $('.dialog').empty();
    }

    $('body').click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is("input, .close")) {
            $('.dialog').removeClass('open');
        }
    });
    // initDialog();
    function parselocalstorage(name) {
        var str = localStorage.getItem(name);
        var obj = JSON.parse(str) || []
        let arr = Object.keys(obj).map((k) => obj[k]) || []
        return arr
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); at the end of the function like this.

```
element.find(".I_delete").click(function () {
                     $('#calendar-popup').hide();
                     if (confirm('are you sure want to delete event?')) {
                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                         var index = events.map(function (x) { return x.id; }).indexOf(event.id);
                         events.splice(index, 1);
                         localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events));

                         events = parselocalstorage('events')
                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');


                     }
                 });
```

I hope this solve your problem :).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you only update the state not the view. You need to re-render the view. Framework like angular and react can detect the state change automatically and re-render it. Since you are using Jquery I assuming that you haven't used any framework like that. Since you only post part of the code, I can only give you my best guess, one way to do it is that call the rendering function that you implemented or select the calendar and update it using innerHTML.

Comment: Could you provide me the code that you use to render the events on the calendar?

Comment: Sure. That will be great.